# Running cqlsh script from Scala

Tags: scala, cassandra, cqlsh

I am trying to execute a .cql script from my application, which is written in Scala. It does work if I am logged in Cassandra, but when I try to automatize the task it fails. This is what I got so far:

```
    def executeScript(path: String, user: String, password: String, host: String): Unit = {

    val command = s"cqlsh -f $path -u '$user' -p '$password' $host;"

    val execution = command.!
}
```

And this is the trown exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 2434, in <module>
    main(*read_options(sys.argv[1:], os.environ))
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 2413, in main
    encoding=options.encoding)
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 479, in __init__
    load_balancing_policy=WhiteListRoundRobinPolicy([self.hostname]),
  File "/usr/share/cassandra/lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.10.zip/cassandra-driver-3.10/cassandra/policies.py", line 417, in __init__
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Since it works in Cassandra, I don't knwow what to change. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `;` character at the end - just remove it after `$host`, otherwise it will be passed as part of hostname